# how to eliminate the empty row with pop-up get closed in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my hbs I have created an dynamic table.
I have created an ember bootstrap modal which appears as a button click present in my hbs but without filling any details in the modal when i click anywhere on the screen modal gets closed and an empty row in created in the table.
I want to eliminate that empty row. How to deal with this problem?

here is my code of the modal:

```
show: function() {

  this.$('.modal').modal().on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    this.sendAction('close');
  }.bind(this));  
}.on('didInsertElement')
```

Comment: what is inside the `modal` dialog? how does it relate the table; I mean how is the data to be filled within the modal is handled to be displayed within the table?

Comment: It’s hard to say without more information, but a simple way to remove empty rows with jQuery is `$('tr:empty').remove()`